# Matplotlib shows different fonts when saving jpg with respect to png. Why?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I save a plot from matplotlib with the png format, the font is different than when saved as jpg. This is strange behaviour.
[image: jpg image]
[image: png image]

I did run the following code:
When changing the extension into png, the fonts of the resulting image file change.

```
"""
Simple demo of a scatter plot.
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    N = 50
    x = np.random.rand(N)
    y = np.random.rand(N)
    colors = np.random.rand(N)
    area = np.pi * (15 * np.random.rand(N)) ** 2

    plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
    plt.savefig("C:\Temp\myfile.jpg")
    plt.show()
```

Update (27-07-2015): Fixed it using another backend. Did use wxagg. Now using agg which did the trick.

Comment: Are you manually setting the font type? Some example code would be useful.

Comment: can you upload the png and the jpg? And please add your code.

Comment: What I get while trying to save into jpg:


    ValueError: Format "jpg" is not supported.
    Supported formats: eps, pdf, pgf, png, ps, raw, rgba, svg, svgz.


So perhaps in your case the function saving to jpg might be the reason... try saving into png, then convert to jpg with PIL.Image

Comment: Running your code in Ubuntu with matplotlib 1.4.2. does not result in this behaviour. The fonts are the same for the png and jpg.

Comment: In Windows 7, I get the same error as @valtuarte when trying to save in jpg.

Comment: OK thank you all for the feedback. I go with the solution of @valtuarte and use PIL for a conversion. This renders both images identical with same fonts. (It is however strange that I do not get the ValueError)

Comment: I just tested the same code on my home windows 8 machine. Both images are similar. So it might be a problem related to my pc at my office.

Comment: I tested the same code in my office (Windows 7, Python(x,y)). Both images have the same font.

Comment: My guess is that it is almost certainly due to font support on the version of PIL / pillow used by matplotlib to render jpeg on your work pc. If you post versions (OS, python, matplotlib and PIL/pillow) for your work pc, we can probably repro / diagnose.

Comment: @rene Glad to see you solved it :) Can you add a [self answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than update the question?  That way it shows as answered and also is more likely to hang around for the benefit of future readers who might discover it via search.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using another backend. Did use wxagg. Now using agg which did the trick.